# React with TypeScript: how to type useState hook with previous state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React + TS application and I'm writing a custom hook to update the header of a table. Basically, I can click on different checkboxes and hide/show that specific column of the table.

```
const useHeader = (headerConfiguration: TableHeader[]) => {
  const [header, setHeader] = useState(headerConfiguration);

  const updateHeader = (column: string) => {
     setHeader(prevState => {                       // <- this line has the error
       prevState.forEach(el => {
         if (el.name === column) el.visible = !el.visible;
       });
     });
  };

  return {
    header,
    updateHeader,
  };
};

export default useHeader;
```

As the code shown, I need to update the `visible` property based on the `column` name.

Currently I have an error tough:

> Argument of type '(prevState: TableHeader[]) => void' is not
> assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<TableHeader[]>'.
> Type '(prevState: TableHeader[]) => void' is not assignable to type
> '(prevState: TableHeader[]) => TableHeader[]'.
> Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'TableHeader[]'.

I get what the error is saying but I'm not sure how to fix it, if I write the same function using the library Immer it works without any error:

```
   setHeader(
     produce(header, draftHeader => {
       draftHeader.forEach(el => {
         if (el.name === column) {
           el.visible = !el.visible;
         }
       });
     }),
   );
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When not using immer, you're responisble to *produce* **and** *return* a **new** state. So instead of manipulating `prevState` you need to create a copy of it, with the changes you require applied.

For example, with something like this:

```
const updateHeader = (column: string) => {
  setHeader(prevState => {
    // return a copy prevState
    return prevState.map(
      el => el.name === column
        ? {...el, visible: !el.visible} // copy inner item, if changed
        : el;
    );
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
const useHeader = (headerConfiguration: TableHeader[]) => {


const [header, setHeader] = useState(headerConfiguration);



const updateHeader = (column: string) => {
    header.forEach(el => {
      if (el.name === column) el.visible = !el.visible;
    });
    setHeader(header);
  };

  return {
    header,
    updateHeader,
  };
};

export default useHeader;
```